# Dart resource package throws Unsupported operation in Flutter

Tags: flutter

My Flutter project uses an own developed Dart package that in turn depends on the [resource](https://pub.dev/packages/resource) package. Using my package in a Flutter project throws an `Unsupported operation` as soon as it hits a line where resource is used like this `resource.readAsString(encoding: utf8)`:

```
  Unsupported operation: Isolate.resolvePackageUri
  dart:isolate                              Isolate.resolvePackageUri
  package:resource/src/resolve.dart 11:20   resolveUri
  package:resource/src/resource.dart 74:21  Resource.readAsString
```

Is there a way to get this to work? Or alternatively, should I report a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, the `Isolate.resolvePackageUri()` method is still not supported on Flutter.

See the GitHub issue #14815:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14815

So:

- **Is there a way to get this to work?** No. You must avoid package URIs (and all APIs / libraries dealing with them).
- **Should I report a bug somewhere?** No. This issue was already raised on the GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you. But technically it doesn't answer the question. Is it "no there is no way to get this to work and no don't report a bug because it's a known issue (#14815)" ?

Comment: That's it! There is no solution to this problem currently (apart from avoiding completely package URIs), and the bug report already exists. More info: https://pub.dev/packages/resource => package URIs are not compatible with AOT compilation (i.e. Flutter).

Comment: Thank you for completing the answer, much appreciated.